# Unable to install Cordova with npm

Tags: node.js, cordova

Installing Cordova with Nodejs, i got this error  :

```
npm WARN installMany normalize-package-data was bundled with npm@1.3.4, but bund
led package wasn't found in unpacked tree.
```

The error comes after the command npm install -g cordova

What can be the solution please ?

Thnx

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue, so i present here what i did to solve it for anyone who may have the same problem : 
I thought about reinstalling Nodejs. So i removed it and installed it again but nothing worked, then i took an installation directory of Nodejs in another computer (which works fine) and copied it to my computer and referenced it in the path environnement variable and every thing worked fine !!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with cordova and the version of the node.js. The latest version for Node.js (as of today for windows) is problematic with cordova. I went back a few versions and Node-v0-10-36-stable is working fine so far. Other versions may also work but I can only speak for v0.10.36.

http://blog.nodejs.org/2015/01/26/node-v0-10-36-stable/