# Cordova Installation issue: on Windows 7

Tags: node.js, cordova

I'm trying to set up Cordova on my machine.  I have successfully setup the JDK, Node.js, and git.

When I type `npm install cordova -g` I get the following output:

```
npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current: {
"node":"4.1.1","npm":"2.14.4"})
C:\Users\matt.paisley\AppData\Roaming\npm\cordova -> C:\Users\matt.paisley\AppDa
ta\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\bin\cordova
cordova@5.3.3 C:\Users\matt.paisley\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova
├── underscore@1.7.0
├── q@1.0.1
├── nopt@3.0.1 (abbrev@1.0.7)
└── cordova-lib@5.3.3 (valid-identifier@0.0.1, unorm@1.3.3, osenv@0.1.0, propert
ies-parser@0.2.3, bplist-parser@0.0.6, semver@4.3.6, dep-graph@1.1.0, shelljs@0.
3.0, rc@0.5.2, xcode@0.8.0, elementtree@0.1.6, npmconf@2.1.2, tar@1.0.2, cordova
-serve@0.1.3, cordova-app-hello-world@3.9.0, aliasify@1.7.2, cordova-registry-ma
pper@1.1.12, npm@2.14.7, glob@5.0.15, cordova-js@4.1.1, request@2.47.0, init-pac
kage-json@1.9.1, plist@1.1.0)
```

When I type `cordova` at the system prompt I get:

> cordova is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

I checked my Firewall `log` and `node.exe` is allowed to make outbound calls. Is there anything else that I may have done wrong?

I am using the following versions:
  git version 2.5.3.windows.1
  node js version v4.1.1
  javac 1.8.0_20

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Don't know how important this is but as far as i know the command is `sudo npm install -g cordova` not `sudo npm install cordova -g` but like i said, i don't know how important the position of the flag -g (gloabl) is. Also check your system `%PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer with the following post:

[Unable to install Cordova with npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29413801/unable-to-install-cordova-with-npm)

Essentially the current version of node.js has some issues.  After I uninstalled it and installed Node-v0-10-36-stable, I was able to successfully deploy cordova.

This version of node.js can be found at: https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v0.10.36/